# Splitting User and Profile issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm probably missing something trivial...

I have a User model that 'has_one' UserProfile:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token

    has_many :user_roles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
    has_one  :user_profile, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles, :user_profile, allow_destroy: true

    validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: TextUtils::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

    def User.new_remember_token
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def User.digest(token)
      Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
    end

    def admin?
      in_role?(Role::ADMINISTRATOR)
    end

    def in_role?(role)
      !self.roles.find_by_name(role).nil?
    end

    private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

and I have a UserProfile model that 'belongs_to' User:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

    validates :first, :last, :ssn, :title, :division, :phone_home, :phone_mobile, :phone_work, :phone_work_ext, 
    :emergency_phone, :emergency_name, :emergency_relation, presence: true
    validates :personal_email, format: { with: TextUtils::VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

When I try to seed the database as such (or any other way where profile is assigned to user):

```
# Admin
admin = User.create!(email: "admin@work.com", password: "secret", password_confirmation: "secret",
  user_profile: UserProfile.new(
  first: "Admin", 
  last: "User", 
  address_attributes: {line1: "123 Fake Street", line2: "Suite 1", city: "Some City", state: "FL", zip_code: "11111"},
  ssn: "123-45-6789", 
  phone_work: "(111) 222-3333",
  phone_work_ext: "110",
  personal_email: "test@home.com")
)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
    rake aborted!
    ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: user_profile_id
    C:/work/Portal/db/seeds.rb:12:in `'
    Tasks: TOP => db:seed
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.  Any help will be appreciated!  I am using Rails 4.1.4, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything has to be passed as (nested) hash(es):

```
admin = User.create!({
  email: "admin@work.com",
  password: "secret",
  password_confirmation: "secret",
  user_profile_attributes: {
    first: "Admin", 
    last: "User", 
    address_attributes: {
      line1: "123 Fake Street",
      line2: "Suite 1",
      city: "Some City",
      state: "FL",
      zip_code: "11111"
    },
    ssn: "123-45-6789", 
    phone_work: "(111) 222-3333",
    phone_work_ext: "110",
    personal_email: "test@home.com"
  }
})
```

## Update

Working example:

```
$ rails new testapplication
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

$ cd testapplication/
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake 10.3.2
Installing i18n 0.6.11
Using json 1.8.1
Installing minitest 5.4.1
Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing activesupport 4.1.1
Installing builder 3.2.2
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Installing actionview 4.1.1
Installing rack 1.5.2
Installing rack-test 0.6.2
Installing actionpack 4.1.1
Installing mime-types 1.25.1
Installing polyglot 0.3.5
Installing treetop 1.4.15
Installing mail 2.5.4
Installing actionmailer 4.1.1
Installing activemodel 4.1.1
Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Installing activerecord 4.1.1
Using bundler 1.6.1
Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Installing execjs 2.2.1
Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
Installing thor 0.19.1
Installing railties 4.1.1
Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
Installing hike 1.2.3
Installing multi_json 1.10.1
Installing jbuilder 2.1.3
Installing jquery-rails 3.1.1
Installing tilt 1.4.1
Installing sprockets 2.11.0
Installing sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Installing rails 4.1.1
Installing rdoc 4.1.1
Installing sass 3.2.19
Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
Installing sdoc 0.4.1
Installing spring 1.1.3
Installing sqlite3 1.3.9
Installing turbolinks 2.3.0
Installing uglifier 2.5.3
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!

$ ./bin/rails g model user
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140829201904_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/user_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/users.yml
$ ./bin/rails g model user_profile user:references test:integer
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140829201916_create_user_profiles.rb
      create    app/models/user_profile.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/user_profile_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/user_profiles.yml
$ ./bin/rake db:migrate
== 20140829201904 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0012s
== 20140829201904 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0013s) =============================

== 20140829201916 CreateUserProfiles: migrating ===============================
-- create_table(:user_profiles)
   -> 0.0010s
== 20140829201916 CreateUserProfiles: migrated (0.0010s) ======================
```

Then edited the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile
end
```

UserProfile is already correct:

```
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and run the create statement:

```
$ ./bin/rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
2.1.0 :001 > User.create({user_profile_attributes: {test: 5}})
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-29 20:21:41.860036"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-29 20:21:41.860036"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "user_profiles" ("created_at", "test", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-29 20:21:41.864624"], ["test", 5], ["updated_at", "2014-08-29 20:21:41.864624"], ["user_id", 1]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
 => #<User id: 1, created_at: "2014-08-29 20:21:41", updated_at: "2014-08-29 20:21:41"> 
2.1.0 :002 > User.last.user_profile.inspect
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  UserProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "user_profiles".* FROM "user_profiles"  WHERE "user_profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
 => "#<UserProfile id: 1, user_id: 1, test: 5, created_at: \"2014-08-29 20:21:41\", updated_at: \"2014-08-29 20:21:41\">"
```

Comment: Thanks, GhostGambler.  I have tried this before, and even now the create is failing with the same error.  Note, that I have changed 'user_profile:' and 'address:' in your snippet to 'user_profile_attributes:' and 'address_attributes:' respectively, otherwise actual Objects are expected instead of hashes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the keys were wrongly named. But it makes no sense, that you receive the same error message? I would only expect this error message in two cases: Either your models relationships are wrong (as you wrote them above, I do not see an error) or you passed an object into the method instead of a hash.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is what's happening.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck.  :)

Comment: Double check if everything is correct. I added a working example to my post. It definitely works.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer, as it is most certainly how things should work.  I have not got my error fixed, but now I think there may be something with my environment that causes the issue, not Rails or ActiveRecord...  Thanks for posting an example.

Comment: You could try to localize the bug by bringing your code step-by-step into the form of my working example. (Remove additions to the models, try the create call from the console, …) And be reminded that you need to [`reload!`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7830713/3340665) the console, when you make changes to your models.

Comment: Got it sorted, finally!  Turns out, when I refactored relationship I forgot to change reference_to_user => reference_to_user_profile in Address model.  Thanks for responding.