# Rails: Rolify gem not updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console, savechanges, rolify, update-attributes

So here's is what I did:

Select the user:

```
>> user = User.find(337633)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<User id: 337633, name: "Restaurant Guy", email: "restaurant@guy.com", mobile: "8000088888", image: "", password_digest: "$2a$10$H3TlQT1DdGOPQjSR7b1st.SVvAg5XiFidrfqzyqz0RW...", created_at: "2017-02-23 18:19:29", updated_at: "2017-02-23 18:21:43", uid: nil, provider: nil, verified_at: nil, location_id: nil>
```

Check number of roles:

```
>> user.roles.length
  Role Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 337633]]
1   #customer role
```

Grant the selected user a role on a specific resource:

```
>> user.grant :restaurant_admin, Restaurant.first
  Restaurant Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" ORDER BY "restaurants"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = $1 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $2 AND "roles"."resource_id" = $3 ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT $4  [["name", "restaurant_admin"], ["resource_type", "Restaurant"], ["resource_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  HABTM_Roles Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users_roles".* FROM "users_roles" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 337633]]
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<Role id: nil, name: "restaurant_admin", resource_type: "Restaurant", resource_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = 4
>> user.save
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
true
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."mobile" = $1 AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["mobile", "8000088888"], ["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["email", "restaurant@guy.com"], ["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
```

And save it:

```
>> user.save
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
true
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."mobile" = $1 AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["mobile", "8000088888"], ["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["email", "restaurant@guy.com"], ["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Reload from database:

```
>> reload!
Reloading...
true
```

Check if the saved value is present

```
>> user = User.find(337633)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<User id: 337633, name: "Restaurant Guy", email: "restaurant@guy.com", mobile: "8000088888", image: "", password_digest: "$2a$10$H3TlQT1DdGOPQjSR7b1st.SVvAg5XiFidrfqzyqz0RW...", created_at: "2017-02-23 18:19:29", updated_at: "2017-02-23 18:21:43", uid: nil, provider: nil, verified_at: nil, location_id: nil>
>> user.roles.length
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 337633]]
1  #customer role :(
```

Why wasn't the update persisted?

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

**UPDATE**: Looks like there's no mistake on saving the updated parts but seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/381) in `rolify` gem when operated on `Rails 5+`

---

**UPDATE 2**: The aforementioned bug was resolved I believe, and I finally found what was causing the `ROLLBACK` -> failing to [include resourcify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/381).

Comment: should I do a `save` on the roles? something like `user.roles.save` to update the roles array?

Comment: what is the `ROLLBACK` doing when I granted the role? is that causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to include `resourcify` on the resource that should be assigned to the role and the `ROLLBACK` was happening as the link was broken.

**And I also found that `user.save` is useless here** as the roles get into the db right after you grant them

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7830875/3257186) try to call reload on the user object directly:

```
user.reload
```

It seems, that the rails console doesn't reload classes once they're referenced.

Comment: `reload` doesn't help! :( Roles not getting updated. and could it be the `ROLLBACK` that's causing this?

Comment: and btw even if `user` obj is cached and doesn't get reset during `reload!`, rails **should fetch it from db** on my command `user = User.find(id)` _which I did after `reload!`_ right?

Comment: true. can you post the `grant` method?

Comment: it is the alias of `add_role` method in `rolify` gem. Details [here](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Usage#add-a-role-to-a-user)

Comment: have you tried the gem's methods add_role and has_role? how did you set up the db?

Comment: yes, `grant` is functioning **exactly** as `add_role`, and `user.has_role? :customer` returns `true`. The gem's _probably_ working fine

Answer (score 0):

When you grant the selected user a role on a specific resource, it seems that there's no record add to `users_roles`.

```
>> user.grant :restaurant_admin, Restaurant.first
  Restaurant Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" ORDER BY "restaurants"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = $1 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $2 AND "roles"."resource_id" = $3 ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT $4  [["name", "restaurant_admin"], ["resource_type", "Restaurant"], ["resource_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
  HABTM_Roles Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users_roles".* FROM "users_roles" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 337633]]
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<Role id: nil, name: "restaurant_admin", resource_type: "Restaurant", resource_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = 4
>> user.save
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
true
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."mobile" = $1 AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["mobile", "8000088888"], ["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND ("users"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["email", "restaurant@guy.com"], ["id", 337633], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
```

it was ROLLBACKed. 
so i think there's something wrong with the method `user#grant`

Comment: so maybe a **major** bug in the `rolify` gem?

Comment: i don't think it is not a bug, but you should check if this return a value that is not nil `Role.where(name: 'restaurant_admin', resource_type: 'Restaurant', resource_id: 1)`

Comment: there was no such entry **until I added `resourcify`** and then did a `grant` command; It is a bug in a way that it does not show the error _that `resourcify` is missing_ or telling that the rel is broken